# Array split in Hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

I have a hive table "my_table" with an array `<bigint>` column recommended_ids

underlying data:

```
user_id|recommended_ids                                                                                   
1111198|[179995, 11186, 553248631043262469, 601906, 178276, 602901, 180032, 180016, 178286, 553248632557170387]
11|[178286655, 5532486]
```

I need output like this (first 5 recommended_ids as 5 columns, it can be less than 5 as well)

```
user_id col_1     col_2   col_3              col_4  col_5
1111198 179995    11186   553248631043262469 601906 178276
11      178286655 5532486
```

I am doing it like below

```
select
user_id
,split(recommended_ids,",")[0] as col_1
,split(recommended_ids,",")[1] as col_2
,split(recommended_ids,",")[2] as col_3
,split(recommended_ids,",")[3] as col_4
,split(recommended_ids,",")[4] as col_5
from my_table
```

But getting below error

FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardListObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the column is already an `array`, you can just get the elements by indices. No `split` needed.

```
select
user_id
,recommended_ids[0] as col_1
,recommended_ids[1] as col_2
,recommended_ids[2] as col_3
,recommended_ids[3] as col_4
,recommended_ids[4] as col_5
from my_table
where size(recommended_ids) >= 5 --to filter for array lengths >= 5
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431869/vamsi-prabhala  This works, but how can I handle situations where I have less than 5 recommended_ids in the data , then indices would be out of bounds?

Comment: Check for the length of array in that case in where condition

Comment: I am going with below to handle the "IndexOutOfBoundsException" exception        select
user_id
,case when size(recommended_ids) >= 1 then recommended_ids[0]  else null end as col_1
,case when size(recommended_ids) >= 2 then recommended_ids[1]  else null end as col_2
,case when size(recommended_ids) >= 3 then recommended_ids[2]  else null end as  col_3
,case when size(recommended_ids) >= 4 then recommended_ids[3]  else null end as col_4
,case when size(recommended_ids) >= 5 then recommended_ids[4]  else null end as  col_5
from my_table